# $ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it} - a e^{i \phi}} \ln(|e^{it} - e^{i \theta}|) dt$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to evaluate

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it} - a e^{i \phi}} \ln(|e^{it} - e^{i \theta}|) dt$$

where $a \in (0, 1)$.

I'm currently doing a countour integral:

$$= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \oint \frac{z \ln(|z - e^{i \theta}|)}{z - a e^{i \phi}} \frac{dz}{i z}$$
$$=  \frac{2 \pi i}{2 \pi i} \ln(|a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}|)$$
$$=  \ln(|a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}|)$$

This is a real result (ie: there's no imaginary component).  I get the same answer when I integrate numerically with some sample values, at least in the real part, but the numerical integral also has a non-zero imaginary component of roughly the same magnitude, and I don't understand where that's coming from.

Why does my analytic result disagree with my numerical result?  Have I made a mistake in my contour integration?

Comment: You apply Cauchy's integral formula, but $\ln(|z - e^{i \theta}|)$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: @Raskolnikov indeed.  I was vaguely treating it as $\lim_{b \to 1} \ln(|bz - e^{i \theta}|)$, where as long as $b \in [0, 1)$ it's holomorphic inside the unit circle, but I don't know rigorously if I can do that.

Comment: No, it doesn't only fail at one point. It fails to be holomorphic at all points since your function takes only real values. Hence it can never satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 1):

As @Raskolnikov pointed out $\ln(|z|)$ isn't holomorphic.  However, $\ln(|z|) = \frac{1}{2} (\ln(z) + \ln(\overline{z}))$.  In this case, we can use that to make this to split the integral in to two holomorphic parts:

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it} - a e^{i \phi}} \ln(|e^{it} - e^{i 
\theta}|) dt$$
$$ = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it} - a e^{i \phi}} \ln(e^{it} - e^{i \theta}) dt + \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it} - a e^{i \phi}}\ln(e^{-it} - e^{-i \theta})) dt$$
$$=  \frac{1}{4 \pi i} \oint \frac{z}{z - a e^{i \phi}} \ln(z - e^{i \theta}) \frac{dz}{z} - \frac{1}{4 \pi i} \oint \frac{dz}{z (1 - a z e^{i \phi})}\ln(z - e^{-i \theta})$$
$$= \frac{2 \pi i}{4 \pi i} (\ln (a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}) - \ln(-e^{-i \theta}))$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} (\ln (a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}) - i (\pi - \theta))$$